# Error building Boost 1.49.0 with GCC 4.7.0

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

I'm trying to build Boost 1.49.0 using GCC 4.7.0 (MinGW). I keep getting the following error message several dozen times:

> c:\tools\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/cmath:1096:11: error: '::hypot' has not been declared

Line 1096 of `cmath` contains

```
using ::hypot;
```

`cmath` includes `math.h` which declares the `hypot` function as

```
extern double __cdecl hypot (double, double); /* in libmoldname.a */
```

In both files, a couple of lines after the ones quoted above, are identical statements for the `hypotl` function (except the type is `long double` instead of `double`) and that one seems happy.

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the answer in [this forum post](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-Python-Compile-Error-s-GCC-via-MinGW-w64-tp3165793p3166757.html). It seems that *pyconfig.h* has the following lines:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(_WIN32)
// ...
#define hypot _hypot
// ...
#endif /* GNUC */
```

but *cmath* included with MinGW expects the function to be named `hypot` and not `_hypot`, which causes the compilation errors.

The fix was to include the following to my bjam command line's *cxxflags* option

```
bjam ... cxxflags="-include cmath "
```

This indicates that g++ should include the *cmath* header at the beginning of every source file.

Comment: Thanks, that did the Trick!

Answer (score 17):

The answer by @Praetorian correctly identifies the problem.
On the other hand, the Python headers are technically meant to come before any others.
In addition, sometimes the accepted solution does not work or is inconvenient in the build system, so I came up with an alternate solution.
Add the following flag to the call to g++:

```
-D_hypot=hypot
```

This makes it so that the harmful macro in the Python headers becomes a no-op, and the compilation error goes away.

Comment: Worked for me when building OpenCV while "-include cmath" didn't.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see this happens when compiling with MingW, using -std=c++0xx, and including Python.h before cmath. And note that cmath is included by quite a few other header files...
Note that the problem is not Boost specific. Complicating fact is that in my standard MingW - Visual Studio cross compilation setup, Visual Studio 2010 needs in Debug mode to have Python.h included before many other standard include files.
Solution is to include cmath first, followed by Python.h, so you get code like:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <Python.h>
#include < other standard headers >
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is identified correctly by @Praetorian.

In my case it only appears in one file.So I simply add

`#define _hypot hypot` before `#include <Python.h>`

and works.

Hope this can be enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the preprocessed unit. I guess you'll find something like "#undef hypot".

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this error in Code Blocks when I added the following path in the Linker

```
C:\Python36-32\libs
```

and put two libs on the link libraries: **libpython36.a** and **python36.lib**.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line

```
#define _hypot hypot
```

at the first of your `Python.h` file that it is stored in your python installation directory. somewhere like `C:\Python27\include`.