# Error building OpenCV with mingw under Windows 10

Tags: windows, opencv, cmake, mingw

I tried to build the opencv Library on my Windows 10 PC.
I managed to generate everything from source with cmake. (Nothing red, no errors).
When I try to build everything with mingw (mingw32-make install) 
It starts building and after a while I get the following error.

```
[ 76%] Building CXX object modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/Python34/include/Python.h:8:0,
             from C:\OpenCV\opencv-master\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp:6:
C:/Python34/include/pyconfig.h:440:5: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #if _MSC_VER >= 1800
 ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/include/c++/math.h:36:0,
             from C:/Python34/include/pyport.h:328,
             from C:/Python34/include/Python.h:50,
             from C:\OpenCV\opencv-master\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp:6:
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/include/c++/cmath:1133:11: error: '::hypot' has not been declared
using ::hypot;
       ^~~~~
modules\python3\CMakeFiles\opencv_python3.dir\build.make:179: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:7051: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I found the following ["Error: '::hypot' has not been declared" in cmath while trying to embed Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683358/error-hypot-has-not-been-declared-in-cmath-while-trying-to-embed-python)

But could not figured it out.
Can Anyone hint me in the direction. Where are those includes in the case of building OpenCV?

Versions: 
OpenCV 3.2.0,
CMake 3.4.1,
GNU Make 4.1

Any help qould be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following file

```
C:\OpenCV\opencv-master\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp
```

and see if 
`#include "Python.h"`
comes before `#include <cmath>`.
In that case exchange the order, i.e. write

```
#include <cmath>
#include "Python.h"
```

so that `cmath` comes before `Python.h`.
Try to build and see if that solves at list the error that you reported.

Comment: In my case cmath was not included at all in the file you mentioned. I added it before the Python include and started over again. But nothing changed. http://pastebin.com/uhMJJx8g that is my cv2.cpp file. I noticed that it is complaining about _MSC_VER not beeing declared. Can this be a source of errors?