# Error 2 while building omniORB from Source

Tags: python, cygwin, mingw, corba, omniorb

I am trying to install omniORB from source downloaded from this link:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/omniorb/files/omniORB/omniORB-4.2.4/

I did what the readme.win32 specified (install Cygwin, I already have Python3 with Anaconda, install MinGW instead of Visual Studio, add to env PATH, made changes in /config/config.mk and \mk\platforms\x86_win32_mingw.mk ...), build \src\tool\omkdepend and then \src with make export,

I always get this error though:

```
$ make export making export in src/tool... make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/HOMEWARE/omniORB-4.2.4/src/tool' making export in src/tool/omniidl... make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/HOMEWARE/omniORB-4.2.4/src/tool/omniidl' making export in src/tool/omniidl/cxx... make[3]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/HOMEWARE/omniORB-4.2.4/src/tool/omniidl/cxx' ../../../../bin/x86_win32/omkdepend -D__cplusplus -D__GNUG__
-D__GNUC__ -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE=<Python.h> -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC=<pythread.h> -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="0x2630" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 idlc.cc idlpython.cc idlfixed.cc idlconfig.cc idldump.cc idlvalidate.cc idlast.cc idlexpr.cc idlscope.cc idlrepoId.cc idltype.cc idlutil.cc idlerr.cc lex.yy.cc y.tab.cc C:\HOMEWARE\omniORB-4.2.4\bin\x86_win32\omkdepend.exe: warning:  idlpython.cc, line 237: unknown directive == "#warning "Please use an up-to-date version of gcc! (>2.91 recommended)"" making export in src/tool/omniidl/cxx/cccp... make[4]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/HOMEWARE/omniORB-4.2.4/src/tool/omniidl/cxx/cccp' gcc -c
-O2 -mthreads -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I../../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -ocexp.o cexp.c gcc -c -O2 -mthreads -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I../../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -occcp.o cccp.c gcc -c -O2 -mthreads -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I../../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oconfig.o config.c gcc -c -O2 -mthreads -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.
-I../../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oalloca.o alloca.c gcc -c -O2 -mthreads -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I../../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oindex.o index.c
+ rm -f omnicpp.exe
+ gcc -oomnicpp.exe -mthreads -Wl,--enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -L../../../../../lib/x86_win32 cexp.o cccp.o config.o alloca.o index.o (dir="../../../../../bin/x86_win32"; files="omnicpp.exe"; for file in $files; do if [ ! -d $dir ]; then (umask 022; set -x; mkdir -p $dir); fi; dirs='. .'; case "$file" in /*) fullfile="$file";; *) fullfile=""; for _dir in $dirs; do if [ -f $_dir/$file ]; then if [ "$_dir" = "." ]; then fullfile="$file"; else fullfile="$_dir/$file"; fi; break; fi; done; if [ ! "$fullfile" ]; then echo "ERROR: Cannot find $file in $dirs"; exit 1; fi;; esac; base=`basename $file`; if [ -f $dir/$base ] && cmp $fullfile $dir/$base >/dev/null; then echo "File $base hasn't changed."; else (set -x; install -c  $fullfile $dir); fi; done; )
+ install -c omnicpp.exe ../../../../../bin/x86_win32 make[4]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/HOMEWARE/omniORB-4.2.4/src/tool/omniidl/cxx/cccp' g++ -c
-O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oy.tab.o y.tab.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -olex.yy.o lex.yy.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oidlerr.o idlerr.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oidlutil.o idlutil.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oidltype.o idltype.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oidlrepoId.o idlrepoId.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oidlscope.o idlscope.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oidlexpr.o idlexpr.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oidlast.o idlast.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oidlvalidate.o idlvalidate.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oidldump.o idldump.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oidlconfig.o idlconfig.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oidlfixed.o idlfixed.cc g++ -c -O2 -mthreads -IC:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include -DPYTHON_INCLUDE="<Python.h>" -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC="<pythread.h>" -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="\"0x2630\"" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -oidlpython.o idlpython.cc In file included from c:\homeware\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\math.h:36,
                 from C:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include/pyport.h:194,
                 from C:/HOMEWARE/Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64/include/Python.h:53,
                 from idlpython.cc:31: c:\homeware\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cmath:1121:11: error: '::hypot' has not been declared  1121 |   using ::hypot;
      |           ^~~~~ make[3]: *** [../../../../mk/mingw.mk:335: idlpython.o] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/HOMEWARE/omniORB-4.2.4/src/tool/omniidl/cxx' make[2]: *** [dir.mk:16: export] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/HOMEWARE/omniORB-4.2.4/src/tool/omniidl' make[1]: *** [dir.mk:22: export] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/HOMEWARE/omniORB-4.2.4/src/tool' make: *** [dir.mk:26: export] Error 2
```

Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276984/hypot-has-not-been-declared or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660524/error-building-boost-1-49-0-with-gcc-4-7-0/12124708#12124708

Comment: When you want to use CORBA, maybe have a look at TAOX11, much easier to use API using C++11, see http://www.taox11.org

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen, thanks, it actually helped fix that issue, but still getting other errors,

Comment: Does TAOX work with Python?

Comment: No, TAOX11 is pure C++11, there is no binding for Python yet